# A basic question on weak convergence of measures

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Why do we need separability of the space to talk about weak convergence of measures ?

Comment: We don't need it to talk about weak convergence. But it makes life much more easier.

Comment: @saz: There must be some reason behind it. Because, read the first paragraph of http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Skorokhod_space#References.

Comment: The first paragraph of the References...? As I said: Separability makes things easier in the sense that there are  a lot of theorems which hold only true if the space is separable. But this doesn't mean that we need separability to talk about weak convergence of measures.

Comment: @saz: I want to know what is meant by "easier" ?

Comment: E.g. [Prokhorov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov's_theorem) holds only if the space is separable ... this is just one example for a theorem which holds only true under the assumption of separability.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the definition of the concept of weak convergence of measures requires separability. We can indeed define the weak convergence on any metric space $(X,d)$, saying that the sequence of Borel probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ weakly converges to $\mu$ if for each $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$ continuous and bounded, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu_n(x)=\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu(x).$$

However, separability makes the things easier. For example, in a separable and complete metric space, each probability measure is tight (Ulam's theorem), and a weakly convergent sequence has to be uniformly tight if the space is complete (part of Prokhorov's theorem).

Comment: Thanks. understood it now.